# Possible to monitor the entry changed in iptable in kube-proxy?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy

When creating a service in kuberate, it is kube-proxy to update the iptables, to understand how it update iptables, I tried to use the following command to understand how kube proxy works when creating a service, but there is no log printed. Anyway to log the action on iptables done by kube proxy?

```
kubectl logs -f kube-proxy-qk8hv -n kube-system
```

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Comment: Find this [doc](https://ronaknathani.com/blog/2020/07/kubernetes-nodeport-and-iptables-rules/) might address your concern

Answer (score 0):

I found the command iptables-save can show all the commands acting on iptables.